# /dev/fb1 not present

Tags: hdmi, framebuffer

Just bought my first RPi.  I have my Pi 4 configured with two hdmi monitors using the two hdmi ports.  Everything works fine on hdmi0 for doing standard stuff.  I want to use hdmi1 for direct pixel display by writing to the frame buffer.  I found other examples on how to open and access fb0 (http://raspberrycompote.blogspot.com/2012/12/low-level-graphics-on-raspberry-pi-part_9509.html).  I modified that to open fb1 but it fails on the open().  Investigating this, I found that while there is a /dev/fb0, there is not a corresponding /dev/fb1 on my Pi 4 even though both hdmi ports are connected to monitors.

Is there some additional configuration / setup that needs to be done to have /dev/fb1 accessible?

Comment: Following a >10 year old post for an obsolete OS is futile. You have failed to specify OS but Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye uses a new compositing Windows manager `mutter`, which does not use the X stack.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure about this, and I can't test it without a lot of re-configuration of my machine, but if it doesn't work, it's simple enough to restore the default:

Edit `/boot/config.txt`:

Find this line:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Change it to this:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
```

Re-boot & verify. If this doesn't work, restore the original line & reboot again.

Comment: Tried switching kms and fkms back and forth but that did not resolve the matter.

Comment: @quickfoxlmd: Sorry - thought it was worth a try.